# Do we need the [quake] and [quake2] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags

The [quake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quake) and [quake2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quake2) tags refer to the game(-engine)s created by id Software. Should these tags exist on Stack Overflow?

#### Arguments for

Games such as [Nexiuz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexuiz) or [Xonotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xonotic) use modified versions of the Quake source code as their game engines, and we already have several other game engine tags:

- [unreal-engine4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unreal-engine4)
- [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d)
- [game-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-engine)

Additionally, developers exploring the [original source code](ftp://ftp.idsoftware.com/idstuff/) (or forks such as [DarkPlaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DarkPlaces_engine)) may want to ask questions about the way the game engine works here.

#### Arguments against

We don't seem to have tags for any of the *other* id games, such as Doom, and - weirdly - we don't have a Quake **3** tag; it seems that [quake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quake) is used for [Quake 3-related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22412044/4200092), even though the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/quake/info) indicates that it only refers to the original one<sup>1</sup>.

So, should we keep (either of) these tags? If so, should we also have a distinct [quake3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quake3) tag to go with them, or should we remove the [quake2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quake2) tag and simply use [quake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quake) for everything?

---

<sup>1. [The game dev SE site](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) has the inverse situation - it *does* have a [Quake 3](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quake3) tag, but *doesn't* have tags for Quake or Quake 2.</sup>

Comment: Yes, they should, as there are programmers out there who are experts in coding against the game engines.  I'm assuming.  Niche, but possible.  I'm not sure about which of the game engines are available to code against, so I can't comment on if any of the tags should be merged.  I suppose if it exists, someone will add the tag if they need to, if they can.

Comment: @Will So should we create a separate [Quake 3] tag for those questions which are currently mis-labeled as [Quake]? Although the engines are related, they're rather distinct (different BSP formats, MDL versus MD3, lack of software rendering support in Quake 3, etc.).

Comment: You could, I suppose, if appropriate.  I'm not all up on the subject so I can't provide a definitive answer to that.